# Why I am getting AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" with Python and Tkinkter?

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()

app.title(" BRAIN SYNCRONIZATION SOFTWARE ")

e1=Entry(app).pack()
t1=Text(app).pack()

def InputFun():
        file=open("acad.txt","a")
        file.write("%s;%s"%(t1.get("0.1",END),e1.get()))
        file.close()
b1=Button(app,text="INPUT",command=InputFun,height=3,width=4).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30,pady=30)
```

This is the code I wrote, but I am repeatedly getting the following error when I press the input button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\vonn\Desktop\brain syncronization.py", line 15, in InputFun
    file.write("%s"%t1.get("0.1",END))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Why is it not writing the file?

Comment: @alex :) nice ... that's why I'm here!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
t1=Text(app).pack()
```

should be

```
t1=Text(app)
t1.pack()
```

The Tkinkter `pack()` method returns None, you can't run `.get()` on it, but need to keep `t1` referring to the text object itself.

Comment: @Vonn: Welcome to StackOverflow! "it worked!!! Thanks a MILLION!!! :)" is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Entry(app).pack() will return anything. Do you mean `e1=Entry(app); e1.pack()`?